# Using diffrent threads in OMP for nested for loops

Tags: openmp

Before I start, I should mention that the loops in my original code are not perfectly nested so I cannot use the "collapse" primitive.

I am trying to thread both the outer and inner "for" loops in the following code. The sample below works fine, however, there is a problem! The inner loop is using the same thread IDs of the outer one, which causes performance degradation. My computer has 20 threads and I want those that are idle to be used in the inner loop. So far I could not figure out a solution. Any suggestion?

The output of sample code is like this:

iter (0, 0), tid outer loop: 0, tid inner loop: 0

iter (0, 1), tid outer loop: 0, tid inner loop: 0

iter (0, 6), tid outer loop: 0, tid inner loop: 0

iter (1, 0), tid outer loop: 1, tid inner loop: 0

iter (1, 1), tid outer loop: 1, tid inner loop: 0

iter (1, 6), tid outer loop: 1, tid inner loop: 0

iter (1, 4), tid outer loop: 1, tid inner loop: 2

iter (1, 5), tid outer loop: 1, tid inner loop: 2

iter (1, 2), tid outer loop: 1, tid inner loop: 1

iter (1, 3), tid outer loop: 1, tid inner loop: 1

iter (0, 4), tid outer loop: 0, tid inner loop: 2

iter (0, 5), tid outer loop: 0, tid inner loop: 2

iter (0, 2), tid outer loop: 0, tid inner loop: 1

iter (0, 3), tid outer loop: 0, tid inner loop: 1

iter (2, 0), tid outer loop: 2, tid inner loop: 0

iter (3, 4), tid outer loop: 0, tid inner loop: 2

iter (2, 1), tid outer loop: 2, tid inner loop: 0

iter (3, 5), tid outer loop: 0, tid inner loop: 2

iter (4, 2), tid outer loop: 1, tid inner loop: 1

iter (3, 0), tid outer loop: 0, tid inner loop: 0

iter (3, 2), tid outer loop: 0, tid inner loop: 1

iter (4, 4), tid outer loop: 1, tid inner loop: 2

iter (2, 6), tid outer loop: 2, tid inner loop: 0

iter (4, 5), tid outer loop: 1, tid inner loop: 2

iter (2, 2), tid outer loop: 2, tid inner loop: 1

iter (3, 3), tid outer loop: 0, tid inner loop: 1

and so on!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main (void)
{
  int i,j,thid;
  omp_set_nested(1);

    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) num_threads(3) private(i,j,thid)  schedule(static,1) 
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        thid = omp_get_thread_num();
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(3) schedule(static,2)
        for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        printf("iter (%0d, %0d), tid outer loop: %0d, tid inner loop: %0d\n", i, j, thid, omp_get_ancestor_thread_num(omp_get_level()) );
    }


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine but you must set num_threads only once. If your computer is capable of running 20 threads, set num_threads to 16

```
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) num_threads(16) private(i,j,thid)  schedule(static,1) 
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    thid = omp_get_thread_num();
    //remove num_threads here
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,2)
    for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    printf("iter (%0d, %0d), tid outer loop: %0d, tid inner loop: %0d\n", i, j, thid, omp_get_ancestor_thread_num(omp_get_level()) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your suggestion but it did not change anything...